# Is it possible to distribute Chrome extension and app in one package?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

I have an extension that I'd like users to install along with my app.  The app's purpose is very simple: use raw sockets to interact with a remote service and pass some messages to the extension.  As far as I know, raw sockets are not available to extensions.

I'd like to avoid forcing users to install two separate packages from the Chrome Web Store.  Is there a way to package both into one unit?

If not, what would be the recommended practice in this case?

The target platform is Chromebook/Chrome OS.

Thanks.

Comment: That isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible, otherwise there would be no reason to have both (apps and extensions).

But you can encourage your users to install extension from your app and vice versa.

And you can send [messages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessageExternal) between extensions and apps so you can ping to check if it is installed or use [management](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#method-get) permission to check.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible, each extension or apps has an unique extension_id.
and has single manifest.

But I think it is pretty good idea :)

I think it should be supported from webstore side.